# solve Ax=b for outrigger A matrix python

Tags: pde, python, finite-difference, sparse-matrix, banded-matrix

I implement **Crank-Nicolson 2D finite-difference method**.

I get a matrix A which is banded with 1 band above and below the main diagonal, but also contains 2 additional bands , further apart from the main diagonal, so it is NOT penta-diagonal.

A picture showing the structure is below. My matrix is the RHS one. The LHS is easy, it's the penta-diagonal one.
[image]

I couldn't find up until now a way to solve Ax = b with A being the RHS matrix from the photo in python.
I could barely find a name for it, in these lecture notes https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/2/2.086/F12/MIT2_086F12_notes_unit5.pdf it is called an 'outrigger' matrix (page 403).

At the moment I am using `spsolve` from from `scipy.sparse.linalg`, into which I feed two arguments, namely `sparse.csc_matrix(A)` and `sparse.csc_array(b)`, where `A` and `b` have been defined initially as `A = sparse.dok_matrix((size, size), dtype=np.complex64)` and `b = sparse.dok_array((size, 1), dtype=np.complex64)`, then populated with values by iterating element by element through them.
It is extremely slow and I was wondering maybe someone more experienced knows a way to exploit the structure appearing in `A`.

Thank you!

Comment: Using a sparse matrix data type for A is good, but your right-hand side vector b is probably dense, so I would just use a normal numpy array for that. There are also better ways to construct A than going through the dok format first, for example, the [diags](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html#scipy.sparse.diags) method.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated. Having a look at it now.

Comment: What's the size of your matrix?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, ideally, I would like to be able to work with matrices of shape around 150.000 x 150.000 (15 x 15 x 10^8), but I could reduce them to 50.000 x 50.000 or 75.000 x 75.000 ...

Comment: These are small matrices. Every finite element solver solves these sorts of matrices in less than a minute on typical laptops today.

Comment: There's an example in https://github.com/mandli/numerical-methods-pdes/blob/master/05_elliptic.ipynb on how to use the spdiags command.  This is for 2D elliptic problems but should not be hard to figure out your problem.